# How to use replaceAll in java without removing the whitespaces?

Tags: java, json, string

I have json string like :

```
{
"type": "abc_onClick",
"selectedComponent": "xyz_Button",
"displayEventName": "On Click",
"eventCategory": "Component Events"
}
```

I am trying to replace `"type": "abc_` with some other string which is working fine but I need to remove whitespaces first. This is how I am doing it :

```
json = json.replaceAll("\\s", "");
json = json.replaceAll("\"type\":\"abc_\", "\"type\":\"newName_\");
```

But while doing so my json structure is getting changed as it is removing all the white spaces and I need the whitespaces as earlier. It is getting changed to :

```
{
"type": "abc_onClick",
"selectedComponent": "xyz_Button",
"displayEventName": "OnClick",
"eventCategory": "ComponentEvents"
}
```

Is there anyway I can achieve it with removing the whitespaces .
Note : I cannot loop or use JsonObject as these are the constraints.

Thanks

Comment: "I need to remove whitespaces first" and "I need the whitespaces as earlier." somehow don't fit well together. I would however propose actually parsing the json into an object with any json-parser and working on that object to make changes. That is going to be a much more robust solution than trying to do string replacements.

Comment: Using basic String replace operations on JSON is a rather bad idea (as you experienced yourself). The proper way would be to use a JSON parser, find the value of `"type"` member and simply change its value.

Comment: String.replaceAll is iterating over the whole string, doesn't that violates your loop constraints? Is it some kind of homework? I would also suggest using JSON parsers.

Comment: I'm bit confused with your code. Why are you replacing all whitespaces first? Why don't you use a whitespace after `"\type\":` directly? Do you need to replace only `abc_` part of `abc_onClick`? If yes, why have you escaped `"` after `abc_` and `newName_`? Anyway you have syntax error in your code.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and post the JSON that you want to get? As I understand, you posted the original JSON and the actual result you are getting which is not the result you want.

Comment: Dont use `replaceAll` if ur not using regex. You can use `replace` instead for the second `replaceAll` you have.

Comment: Ok. Thanks All for all your suggestions !!